# IE9 Developer Toolbar unpins when I hit "Start Debugging"

Tags: internet-explorer-9, ie-developer-tools

When I hit "Start debugging" on the IE9 Developer Toolbar, the IE unpins the toolbar into a floating mode, and greys out ability to re-pin it.

Anyone solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the re-pinning button by clicking the "Stop Debugging" button.

Comment: With due respect, but that cannot be a solution. :-)  I know I can switch a browser as well, but sometime i need to debug IE JS engine.  I might be out of luck.